# How to choose font and text colors for Full-Page backgrounds?

Tags: website-design, typography, critique, mobile

I am an amateur web developer, and I am teaching myself React. Currently, I have been building a personal website [hosted on github pages](https://roy-05.github.io/website/#/).

I want to complete the mobile design first, see some pages below (click for larger size):

[image: home page] [image: about page] [image: contact page]

Q) As you can see the text is not really appealing or "eye-catching". What kind of design choices do more experienced people like yourselves go through in choosing the right font/style, and text colors to make the page vibrant and aesthetic against a colorful background?

Please do not hesitate to criticize and highlight the site's shortcomings.

Comment: Could you please add screenshots instead of a link - screenshots of both the mobile and the web views?

Comment: @Ren Sure! I just added them

Comment: Hey @roy05 I edited your question to make it more focused on the typography aspect, otherwise it's too broad to answer (also fixed your image links). We have guidelines for critique questions, take a look and [edit] your question accordingly https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/681/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work.